# How can I test sending of emails via SendGrid addon without damaging reputation?

Tags: heroku, sendgrid, heroku-addon

I'm using the heroku SendGrid addon to send reminder emails on a schedule defined via heroku scheduler addon.

I want to do some live tests to make sure the heroku scheduler is configured correctly and the emails really send.

The problem is I have an app with a lot of dummy data. E.g. emails like `something_random_ldskfj@example.com` or just `sldkfjsldfjsldkfj@example.com`. I'm worried those emails sent will either go unread, bounce, or something else that SendGrid (or any mailing service) would consider 'negative', and that will mark my account as suspicious.

#### Question

How can I live test my app with heroku scheduler and make sure emails really send at the right times, without incurring the wrath of upsetting the mailing service?

#### What I've thought about doing

- Setting up a *lot* of test gmail accounts - one for each dummy user (undesirable)
- Sending to random emails like `sldfjsd@example.com` and not worrying about the potential consequences (very bad idea)
- Setting up all the dummy accounts in my app with my own, personal email (cannot be done since the database enforces uniqueness of email)
- Use some email addresses Heroku or SendGrid specifically provided for exactly this purpose? (sounds good if it exists?)
- Altering all my test data so that the conditions for emails being sent will never met, except for a very small few (it would work, but it would require changing all the test data and therefore change the look and feel of the app)

Comment: I just stumbled across https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mailtrap I will update once I've tried it

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with people more experienced than me, the advice I received was

- If it's possible to send the emails only to yourself, then do that (not possible in my case)
- No need to test heroku's scheduler (trust that it works)
- **Write really good tests** to ensure the logic and code in your scheduled task works locally, and **trust them** - those test results mean it will work as expected in production